# How to call Grpahql with .Net core from a React component using Axios?

Tags: reactjs, graphql, asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-core-webapi, graphql-dotnet

I am new to graphql and trying to implement Graphql with dot net core using [`graphql-dotnet`](https://github.com/graphql-dotnet/graphql-dotnet) library.

We do not have a dedicated database in this application.  The high level flow of the application is

```
Front End(React) 
    (Calls) > GraphQlController (.Net core)
     (Calls) > Sales force api 
      Send data back to front end.
```

Graphql Setup.

```
public class GraphQLController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly IOptions<ApplicationConfiguration> _configuration;
        public GraphQLController(IOptions<ApplicationConfiguration> config)
        {
            this._configuration = config;
        }
        public async Task<IActionResult> Post([FromBody] GraphQLQuery query)
        {
            var inputs = query.Variables.ToInputs();

            var schema = new Schema()
            {
                Query = new OrderQuery(_configuration)
            };

            var result = await new DocumentExecuter().ExecuteAsync(_ =>
            {
                _.Schema = schema;
                _.Query = query.Query;
                _.OperationName = query.OperationName;
                _.Inputs = inputs;
            }).ConfigureAwait(false);

            if (result.Errors?.Count > 0)
            {
                return BadRequest();
            }

            return Ok(result);
        }
    }

Query class
 public class GraphQLQuery
    {
        public string OperationName { get; set; }
        public string NamedQuery { get; set; }
        public string Query { get; set; }
        public JObject Variables { get; set; }
    }
```

Model Class which used for the de-serialization

```
public class OrderModel
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

Equivalent type in Graphql

```
public class OrderType : ObjectGraphType<OrderModel>
    {
        public OrderType()
        {
            Name = "Order";

            Field(x => x.Id).Description("The ID of the order.");
            Field(x => x.Name).Description("The name of the order");

        }
    }
```

The Query class to call the sales force service

```
public class OrderQuery : ObjectGraphType
    {

        public OrderQuery(IOptions<ApplicationConfiguration> config)
        {
            Field<OrderType>(
                "Order",
                arguments: new QueryArguments(
                           new QueryArgument<IdGraphType> { Name = "id" }),
                resolve: context =>
                {
                    var id = context.GetArgument<object>("id");
                    var service = new SalesForceService(config);
                    var data = service.GetAccountByAccountID(id.ToString());
                    return data;
                });
        }
    }
```

The application compiles fine in visual studio. when i press f5 and run this in the browser. I get this response

```
http://localhost:61625/api/graphql
{"":["The input was not valid."]}
```

When i try to run in postman by passing the following parameters in the body

```
{
OperationName:"test",
NamedQuery: "Orders",
Query:{},
Variables:{id:"123"}
}
```

i get this response "`"A non-empty request body is required."`

Can some one explain to me how do you make a request to graphql end point and what values should be passed in the below parms in postman.

```
{
OperationName:
NamedQuery: 
Query:,
Variables:
}
```

How do you make a similar call from react , We are using axios:.
like below example how are parameters set for the call.

```
 doRestCall = (id) => {
        const model = {
            variable: id
        };

        const headers = {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }



        Axios.post('http://localhost:49776/api/graphql', model, headers)
            .then(result => {
                debugger;
                console.log(result);

            });
        console.log(this.state);
    };
```

Many thanks for the help.

Comment: For your postman example, shouldn't you be setting your `query` param to a string? It seems to be an object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears you're trying to use "named queries" with the use of `NamedQuery`, which is a design pattern with GraphQL.  That design pattern is implemented by having well known queries that are pre-defined and cached on the server.  Looking at your `Controller` you do not have named queries implemented.  You will need to do a regular GraphQL query.

This is what the JavaScript would look like:

```
{
  query: "query MyOrderQuery($id: ID) { order(id: $id) { id name } }",
  variables: {
    id: "123"
  }
}
```

This would be the JSON:

```
{
  "query": "query MyOrderQuery($id: ID) { order(id: $id) { id name } }",
  "variables": {
    "id": "123"
   }
}
```

See https://graphql-dotnet.github.io/docs/getting-started/variables

I also suggest to use Apollo with your React components.
https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/essentials/get-started.html
https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/essentials/get-started.html#request